# Jenkins TFS Plug-in: Keeping the Password Secret

Tags: jenkins, tfs

Our organization currently uses Jenkins (version 2.5) to access Team Foundation Server for our source control. We use the [TFS plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) (version 4.1.0) and it works very well.

Currently when we want to create a new project, we have to manually type in the TFS account username and password into the job's SCM section. The problem is that, eventually, the password to the TFS account is shared by many people. Another problem is that it makes changing the TFS account password difficult because we would have to modify the TFS account credentials in all our projects.

I have read from a [link on Jenkins' issue page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14413) that the issue is resolved somehow. I tried setting secret text and setting the username and password in Jenkins' Manage Credentials section. However, I have not been able to get this to work! When I try to build the project, I get an authorization error.

Does anyone know how to configure Jenkins and the TFS Plug-in so that the TFS password is hidden and comes from one source...?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in Jenkins 2.5, the entered password for TFS is invisible as expected. The password is also invisible in page source by default:

[image]